# I want to restricting the page being loaded in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I want to restricting the page being loaded in chromium. I am trying to check the code of omni box and navigator.cc couldn't find much.

Comment: What kind of pages are you trying to restrict and what should happen when a page is restricted?

Comment: @Asesh The page which renders below , where any url is rendering happens

Comment: @Asesh https://ibb.co/ggX21sr

Comment: You can use policies to do so. More info: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532419?hl=en

Comment: Well according to your question, you want to restrict right? Look at that link. You can use policies to restrict. Not sure what else you want to do.

Comment: @Asesh  I want to restrict the loading but i want to know the new page it was trying to